# How to make game menu in Unity using only the editor?

Tags: unity, game-design

I am trying to implement a game menu screen in which all the levels are locked initially. Just like Angry Birds. When user scores he'll be promoted the level unlocks.

Comment: please clarify what "using only the editor" means. for example byte56 is assuming you mean without any coding at all

Comment: @jhocking how else could this be interpreted?

Comment: um well for starters it could be interpreted as involving some code. After all, script files are created and linked within the editor. And anyway his original title was even more vague on the subject; "using only the editor" was byte's edit, the original title simply said "in unity editor"

Comment: Thanks for understanding jhocking . 
Mr. Byte always edit my question wrongly :/

Comment: How did I edit the question to remove the information where you said you wanted to use code? I removed the "which technology to use" part of your question. As jhocking said, the original title was less clear. You are free to edit your own question for improved clarity if you're not getting the responses you thought you would.

Comment: yeah whether or not he was wrong about his edit doesn't change the fact that *you need to clarify what you meant*. I mean, my first comment wasn't a rhetorical question

Comment: I am really sorry sir Byte56 . You indeed always helped me always. Yup, I know I am still in learning process and soon will be able to make my questions clear . thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Unity doesn't have an interface for creating GUI interfaces in the editor. Further, there may be extensions for this in the Unity marketplace, but it's highly unlikely you'll be able to get away from any coding at all. There's still going to be the requirement to connect the GUI to your game, and many of those interactions are going to require scripts to trigger events in your game, or alter the game state.

Your goal of using the Editor only to make anything more than the most simple game is unrealistic. You'll have to code.

Comment: The PlayMaker extension gives access to most common scripting functions in a visual graph editor. A simple game's GUI could probably accomplish all the tasks it needs this way, although it would be more laborious to set up than simply writing the required code. PlayMaker site: http://www.hutonggames.com/

Comment: I am not saying that I want to do everything from within editor. Of course it's not possible indeed I want to make things easy for me. I already made almost everything from script. Now I want to make my game menu in which I'll have a swipe control to show locked and unlocked levels. Users' can swipe to see locked stages. Just like character selection feature in "Temple Run 2". Vehicle and field selection scene in "Hill Climb". Isn't there anything simpler? I really wanna so it early, as it is my first internship project :(

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do with just the editor. Just the layout of the GUI? The response to the GUI? The animations of the GUI? What do you want to do the editor and what do you want to do in scripts?